# Multiple shortcuts for one action in GTK

Tags: gtk, action, shortcut, vala

What is the best way to bind multiple keyboard shortcuts to one action in GTK+ 3?

I have been searching for an answer to this for a few days and have come up with naught. The function [`gtk_accelerator_parse`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Keyboard-Accelerators.html#gtk-accelerator-parse) does not support comma-deliminated shortcuts. Putting multiple `<accelerator>` tags in a `.ui` file with the same `action` attribute and different `key` attributes also does not work.

I do not want to have to write a custom key press handler just so I can have two shortcuts for one action, but is that really the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since GTK version 3.12 (released on 2014-03-25) there is a new method called [`gtk_application_set_accels_for_action()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkApplication.html#gtk-application-set-accels-for-action) that should help.

Comment: Thanks! I have not done any GTK programming in years, but this method would have been exactly what I wanted if it had only come out 2 years earlier. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way, but it is truly terrible. Using [`gtk_accel_group_connect`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Keyboard-Accelerators.html#gtk-accel-group-connect) I can add additional accelerators for my own functions which can then trigger the action desired based off the key pressed and any modifiers. This however feels like a hack as I am basically creating my own accelerator-to-action map rather than using GTK's.

**I would like to know a better way, if anyone knows of one.**